# How to deserialize the json data like the example below?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I had a HttpWebRequest to a website,and I got the response with some json data like this:

```
[1,"aaa","bbb",[1,"aaa","bbb"]]
```

I find the json format has no keys,but I have to deserialize the data.Anyone has some ideas?

Thx:-)

Comment: Well,how does the server deal with the data?And how can I handle the data in the App client?

Comment: Is that all of what is returned?

Comment: Not all of data.I think I write it as the formats below is better.[1,"aaa","bbb"...,[1,"aaa","bbb"...]]

Comment: Not sure I understand, anyway, you can take the entire Json returned and run it through http://json2csharp.com/ to create poco's to deserialize to.

Answer (score 0):

I used Json.NET to deserialize this.  I'm not sure this is the best way, but it does deserialize:

```
string json = "[1,\"aaa\",\"bbb\",[1,\"aaa\",\"bbb\"]]";
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(json);


foreach (var result in results)
{
    if (result is JArray)
    {
        var array = result as JArray;
        System.Console.WriteLine("  {");
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("     {0}", item);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("  }");

    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx,Robaticus.That's helpful to me:)